# why does tracert only report one hop on failure

Tags: ping, networking

I've been having an issue with one host on my network not being able to ping or tracert machines on the internet while all other hosts can.

When I run a tracert from the machine I get the following output:

> traceroute to
>   host.to.trace.to
>   (XXX.XXX.XXX.X), 30 hops max, 60 byte
>   packets
>   1   (192.168.XXX.XXX)  0.173 ms 0.259 ms *

In this example 192.168.XXX.XXX is the machine I am tracerouting from. So it looks like something funky is going on as no other tracert I've seen includes the source IP.

I am also under the assumption that the tracert should at least be hitting my local router.

Can anyone explain this anomaly?

Comment: A firewall on the host itself? The host using itself as the default gateway?

Comment: Normally the first entry on traceroute would be the gateway.  If the first entry is itself, then apparently the computer believes that *it* is the gateway (though it will print its own address if  it gets a no route to host error for the first hop).  Which could possibly be legit if it is running some kind of VPN.  Can you post the results of `ip route` (or `route -n`) so we can see how it's routing things?

Comment: unfortunately (in a manner of speaking) i fixed the issue I was having and so I can't get any further information. I did look at the output of route but couldn't see anything amiss. BTW the solution was to turn the machine off and on again, go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to pinpoint where the error was occurring and it turns out that peerguardian was assassinating all incoming packets to the host. I'm not exactly sure why the tracert looks like it does but it does explain why tracert was never getting any information.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem on OS X.
I could ping but not traceroute to some sites (twitter.com for example)
The error was "no route to host"
The cure was to remove PeerGuardian.
This program also blocked access to ntp timeservers.

Comment: This would be better as a comment